# Javascript: filter object by array

Tags: javascript

I want to filter an array of object by passing array elements.

```
var filterNumbers = [2, 4];

var obj = [
  {value: 1, lang: 'South'},
  {value: 2, lang: 'North'},
  {value: 3, lang: 'East'},
  {value: 4, lang: 'Test1'},
  {value: 5, lang: 'Test2'},
  {value: 6, lang: 'Test3'},
  ];

let myArray = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
    if (obj[i].value === filterNumbers[i]) {
        myArray.push(obj[i]);
    }
}

console.log(myArray);
```

I see my result is showing `[]`, but instead I want something like the below:

```
[
  {value: 2, lang: 'North'},
  {value: 4, lang: 'Test1'}
];
```

Comment: `obj[i].value === filterNumbers[i]` doesn't make sense because you're going to check `filterNumbers[0, 1, 2, etc]`. You should get in the habit of debugging your code with console.log to check what `filterNumbers[i]` is. Either way, `filterNumbers.includes(obj[i].value)` will do what you want.

Comment: @AndyRay Yes, exactly I want this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the complete answer, idem to the comment of **Andy Ray**

```js
var filterNumbers = [2, 4];

var obj = [
  {value: 1, lang: 'South'},
  {value: 2, lang: 'North'},
  {value: 3, lang: 'East'},
  {value: 4, lang: 'Test1'},
  {value: 5, lang: 'Test2'},
  {value: 6, lang: 'Test3'},
  ];

let myArray = obj.filter(({value})=>filterNumbers.includes(value)) 

console.log(myArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use include method.

```
 var obj = [
      {value: 1, lang: 'South'},
      {value: 2, lang: 'North'},
      {value: 3, lang: 'East'},
      {value: 4, lang: 'Test1'},
      {value: 5, lang: 'Test2'},
      {value: 6, lang: 'Test3'},
      ];
    
    
    var filterNumbers = [2, 4];
    
    let myArray = obj.filter((element) => {
      return filterNumbers.includes(element.value);
    });
    
    console.log(myArray);
```